# Find the Vector Equation of a line perpendicular to the plane.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Question: Find the vector equation $r(t)$ for the line through the point $P = (-1, -5, 2)$ that is perpendicular to the plane $1 x  - 5 y + 1 z = 1$.
Use $t$ as your variable, $t = 0$ should correspond to $P$, and the velocity vector of the line should be the same as the standard normal vector of the plane.

This one is really giving me a hard time.  I know that to find the plane perpendicular to the line I can use the vector n between two points on the line and and the plane.  I cannot wrap my mind around how to reverse this process, particularly because the plane is equal to 1 and not zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vector equation for any line is

$$r(t) = \text{point you want it to pass through} + \text{parameter} \cdot \text{velocity vector}.$$

You want it to pass through the point $P = (-1,-5,2)$ and uses the parameter $t$, so we write

$$r(t) = (-1,-5,2) + t \cdot \text{velocity vector}.$$

As it asked to set the velocity vector as the normal vector to the plane, and that is $N = (1,-5,1)$, we get

$$r(t) = (-1,-5,2) + t (1,5,1).$$

The parameter could have been anything else. We could have chosen $2t, t/7$ or $4t-3$. What difference does it make?

In the first two cases we are changing the speed at which the point walks the line. With $2t$ it walks twice as faster, with $t/7$ it walks $1/7$ slower.

The case $(4t-3)$ changes both speed and at what time you pass through the desired point. With $(4t-3)$ you'll pass through point $P$ at the time $t=3/4$. Using the parameter $t$ ensures that at time $t=0$, so to speak, you begin at point $(-1,-5,2)$.

Comment: There's a typo in the equation, r(t) = (-1,-5,2) + t(1,5,1) should be r(t) = (-1,-5,2) + t(1,-5,1).

Answer (score 5):

In general, the normal vector of the plane $a\cdot x+b\cdot y+c\cdot z+d=0$ is $(a,b,c).$

Hence, the normal vector of the plane $1\cdot x-5\cdot y+1\cdot z-1=0$ is $(1,-5,1).$

Hence, the line can be represented by $t$ as
$$\frac{x-(-1)}{1}=\frac{y-(-5)}{-5}=\frac{z-2}{1}=t.$$
Thus, 
$$r(t)=\left(t-1, -5t-5, t+2\right).$$

Comment: So we ignore the -1 part when we are finding the normal vector, but then we add it in again to the part with z-2 instead of z-1?

Comment: The first half is right. For the second half, the $2$ of $z-2$ is the $z$ of the point $(-1,-5,2)$

Comment: Ah i see, the original point given.  Ok that makes more sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right! You are welcome.