# Find a line that is perpendicular to a plane that passes through a point

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is a homework question I am having difficulty answering. (It is Calc III, but this problem only concerns vectors).

> (A) Find the parametric equations for the line through the point $P =
>  (4, -1, 4)$ that is perpendicular to the plane $3x + 1y  - 5z = 1$. Use
>   "$t$" as your variable, $t = 0$ should correspond to $P$, and the velocity
>   vector of the line should be the same as the normal vector to the
>   plane found directly from its equation.
>
> (B) At what point $Q$ does this line intersect the $yz$-plane?

So Here's what I've tried conceptualizing. First we have point $P$, which we can think of as a vector from the origin. We can also create the normal vector from the plane: $n = \langle 3, 1, -5\rangle$. We can pick a point on the plane that satisfies the equation $p_0 = (2,0,1)$. We can now use this information to start forming a triangle we can solve for. One side: $n - p_0 = \langle 1, 1, -6\rangle$. The hypotenuse can be found with $P - p_0 = \langle 2, -1, 3\rangle$. Which leaves us with one remaining side, which will be a vector within the plane which should give us the point in which the line will intersect with the plane, which we can turn into a vector from the origin and add to the unit vector of $n$ to create our equation.

I *think* finding this remaining side should be how we get all this information, but I don't know if that's right or if that's even the correct approach. Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the Vector Equation of a line perpendicular to the plane.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646420/find-the-vector-equation-of-a-line-perpendicular-to-the-plane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal vector to the given plane and $\mathbf{p}$ is the point through which the line is supposed to pass, then the equation of the line will be of the form $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{p}+t\mathbf{n}$. You already have both those vectors so you don't need anything else.

Comment: I'm aware of that form, but I don't get the correct answer. If I create the unit vector for `n` (`<3/sqrt(35), 1/sqrt(35), -5/sqrt(35)>`)I get the equation `<4, -1, 4> + <3t/sqrt(35), t/sqrt(35), -5t/sqrt(35)>`. WebWork (the application we use for homework) tells me this is wrong when I give it each individual parametric equation (`x(t) = 4+3t/sqrt(35)`, `y(t) = -1+t/sqrt(35)`, `z(t) = 4-5t/sqrt(35)`).

Comment: @BCqrstoO first of all there is no need to normalize the normal vector. Secondly, if still WebWork disagrees then it is making a mistake.

Comment: OH. I see. `t` isn't <i>actually</i> time. It's just an arbitrary variable, so we don't need to the unit vector to calculate the distance at time t. THAT makes sense now (and is returning as correct in WebWork, too)

Answer (score 1):

**A**

We can easily read off a normal vector to the plane, as the $x$ component will be the coefficient of $x$ in the Cartesian form, the $y$ component will be the coefficient of $y$ in the Cartesian form, and so on. Therefore the normal vector to the plane is given by $$ \vec{n}=<3,1,-5>.$$
We know that any line which is perpendicular to the plane must run parallel to $\vec{n}$. Given that we want to find the parametrization (with parameter $t$) of such a line that passes through $P$ at $t=0$, the line is given by $$\vec{r}(t)=<4,-1,4> + t<3,1,-5>.$$

**B**

The $yz$-plane in Cartesian form is $x=0$. So, we want to find for what value of $t$ does the first component of $\vec{r}(t)$ equal to $0$.
$$4 + 3t=0 \implies t=-{4 \over 3}$$
Then substituting this value of $t$ into our parametrization of the line yields
$$\vec{r}\left(-{4 \over 3}\right)= <4,-1,4> -{4 \over 3}<3,1,-5>=<0,-{7\over 3},{32 \over 3}>.$$

So, $Q=\left(0,-{7\over 3},{32 \over 3}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

For (B) you solve
$$
0 = 4 + 3 t
$$
for $t$. Thus $t = -4/3$. And then insert this into the line equation to get the point.